# Accessing a specific component rendered in a for each template

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-events

I'm rendering items (custom lwc component) in a for each template:

```
<template if:true={items.data}>
        <template for:each={items.data} for:item="item">
            <c-lwc-item
                key={item.id}
                sf-id={item.id}
                onsf_item_loaded={handleLoad}>
            </c-lwc-item>
        </template>
</template>
```

The 'sf_item_loaded' is a custom event dispatched by that component.

I'd like, in the handleLoad method triggered in the onsf_item_loaded, to access the c-lwc-item that dispatched that event. Is that possible? I want to do it so that I can call a method from that component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that component using the `.target` property of the event.

```
handleLoad(event) {
    let target = event.target;
    console.log('target ' + target);
    // you can access the function or any property using that like
    target.someFunction();
}
```

Comment: Can't he use the `.target` property of the event?

Comment: Good catch! I did not try that. I will give it a try.

Comment: @RenatoOliveira yes we can use the `event.target`, thanks!!

Comment: So, the event.target returns the component in question? I can let the detail return what it did originally and use the target directly?

Comment: yes @joacoiudica

Comment: Thank you very much!